# passing multiple variables from HTML to Ajax than posting multiple variables from Ajax to php

Tags: php, html, ajax, variables, post

I have the following form, which has 3 values. Class, Section and School. The school is selected from a drop down list that is brought from database.
(for simplicity I have not included those details here.. ) (in reality my code works)

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">                   
<input type="hidden" name="class" value="someclass">
<input type="hidden" name="section" value="somesection">
<select name="school" id="school">          
<option> "school 1"  </option>  
<option> "school 2"  </option>
<option> "school 3"  </option>
<option> "school 4"  </option>
<option> "school 5"  </option>                  
</select>       
</form>
```

I am doing this for the Ajax, and for only 1 variable (the item from list) was working fine, however after adding the class and the section values, I was not able to get those 3 into the Ajax, so that I can post them into the PHP. (syntax might be wrong as this is just copy paste some of the portion of the code.)

```
$("#school").change(function ()
{
 resetValues();


    var school = { school:$(this).attr('value') };
    var class= { class:$(this).attr('value')    };
    var section= { section:$(this).attr('value')};

jQuery.ajax({
                  url: 'getTheData.php',
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType: "xml",
                  data:school&class&section,
                  async: false,
                  success: schoolOnSuccess
            });
```

And naturally I am using _POST to get the values on the getTheData.php the traditional way.

Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using like this, you can serialize the form elements and send.

```
$("#school").change(function ()
{
   resetValues();
   var data = $("#formid").serialize();
   jQuery.ajax({
              url: 'getTheData.php',
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "xml",
              data:data,
              async: false,
              success: schoolOnSuccess
   });
});
```

You can access the values in php function by using the name of form elements.

The advantage of this method is, you don't have to change your script when you add or modify any form element.

Comment: Edwin, thanks a lot. By doing this, right now I am able to get my section and class, however, it seems that I can't get the value which is inside the list.

Comment: Edwin, apparently the value inside the dropdown list is not being passed with the seriable ? is that possible ? because i am able to reference the two other variables by there form names in the other php file where I get them by POST

Comment: @tony9099 You can get all the form elements by this method. But you don't have any value in the dropdown list. So it will not post anything. Add value in the option.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    $('#school').change(function(){
        $.get('getTheData.php', $('#form1').serialize(),
        function(){
           alert('Success!');
        },function(){
           alert('Unsuccess!');
        });
    });
```

and request will send with data on url.

Comment: @tony9099: alert("Sucesss") when the ajax call sucess. Does getTheData.php run correctly?

Answer (score 0):

try this, make your object-data

```
data:{
        'post-field-name' : 'post-field-value'
}
```

so your ajax script will become :

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'getTheData.php',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data:{
        'school' : school,
        'class' : class,
        'section' : section
    }
    async: false,
    success: schoolOnSuccess
});
```